# Flex modes with 3 DIMMs - How it will be behave?

Tags: memory, dual-channel, flex

I have a situation where I need to insert additional RAM, so current setup (2x16GB) in Dual channel will be upgraded with additional 16GB RAM (same speed), but the need for more than original 32GB RAM will be rare.
I have Intel platform and I am aware that this setup will "enter" the flex mode.

My question is, will I have the same performance for tasks that require less then 32GB RAM, or in the other words, will system first "use" all of the RAM in dual channel and then start "consuming" the single channel one (theory vs practical experience)?

Thank you

Comment: Your system will be in flex mode regardless of how much memory your system is consuming. Don’t worry about it. I guarantee you won’t be able to detect a performance drop

Comment: Great info, thank you for the insights